# Environment variable set on process.env (process.env.FLIP_FLOP) not correctly assigned when negated (!process.env.FLIP_FLOP)

Tags: javascript, node.js, boolean, environment-variables

I want to set a boolean variable on process.env in node.js to keep track of the state of an application. I have the following:

```
process.env.FLIP_FLOP = true; // initial state

setInterval(() => {
  process.env.FLIP_FLOP = !(process.env.FLIP_FLOP);
  console.log(process.env.FLIP_FLOP);
}, 1000); // output: true, false, false, false, etc.
```

Can anyone explain why the code above does not work? The following workaround produces the desired results:

```
process.env.FLIP_FLOP = true; // initial state
let flipFlop = process.env.FLIP_FLOP;

// using an interval for illustration
setInterval(() => {
  process.env.FLIP_FLOP = !flipFlop;
  flipFlop = process.env.FLIP_FLOP;
  console.log(process.env.FLIP_FLOP);
}, 1000); // output: true, false, true, false, etc.
```